# OpenVPN static IP and reserve it

Tags: openvpn

I build OpenVPN server, and `topology subnet` config is used. I also want to assign static IPs to specific user.
My question is how to keep this `static IP` from being given out to the rest of the users on the server.
Say, the server setup is like that:

```
server 10.3.18.0 255.255.255.0
route-gateway 10.3.18.1
topology subnet
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/client
```

then I put the following to `/etc/openvpn/client/user1` (**user1** is the client name):

```
ifconfig-push 10.3.18.10 255.255.255.0
```

thus, the user1 client will be assigned the IP is 10.3.18.10, while all other clients will (should) be assigned IPs of 10.3.18.2 -- 10.3.18.9 then 10.3.18.11 -- 10.3.18.254.

And I very afraid that IP=10.3.18.10 will one day also be assigned to any incoming client and user1 (if connect after that) will not be able to get that IP. Yes I can choose static (reserved) IP of 10.3.18.254, not .10, but this won't guarantee that 10.3.18.254 be reserved, right?

Please advice how to deal with that.